# IMobileServiceTableQuery generates OData with the wrong type

Tags: f#, azure-mobile-services

On the client side of my mobile app, I have

```
member private __.PullTable<'a when 'a :> EntityDto> (table: Sync.IMobileServiceSyncTable<'a>) (tableQuery: IMobileServiceTableQuery<'a>) =
    async {
        match CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected with
        | false -> 0 |> ignore
        | true ->
            try 
                do! table.PullAsync (Unchecked.defaultof<string>, tableQuery) |> Async.AwaitTask
            with 
                | ex -> logger.Warning Tag (sprintf "Transient error: Connection failure") (Some ex)
    }
```

which I invoke like this:

```
do! this.PullTable table (table.Where(fun v -> v.OrganiserId = organiserId))
```

The member `organiserId` is an `int` type, defined in the DTO as

```
[<JsonProperty("organiserId")>] member val OrganiserId = 0 with get, set
```

However, on the server side, the generated query has the following path:

```
/tables/EventOrganiserVenueDto?$filter=(organiserId%20eq%202L)&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
```

which translates to

```
/tables/EventOrganiserVenueDto?$filter=(organiserId eq 2L)&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
```

So it looks like the `int` has been misinterpreted as a `long`. Is there any way to fix this that doesn't involve replacing the DTO index with a `short`, as I would eventually like to have more than 32768 entries in my database?